# Make my background music player stop? Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have several views, one of them is an "options" view, in this view there will be a button that will allow the user to click a button to "stop" the background music, or click it to turn it back on. Im pretty sure I have the general idea of how to do this, the problem is, my code isnt working and I am not sure why.

this is the code from the implementation file for the "options" class:

```
  - (IBAction)musicIO:(id)sender {
    MenuViewController *myMusicPlayer = [[MenuViewController alloc] init];

    [myMusicPlayer backgroundMusicStart];

    }
```

it calls the method in my menu code(a different class)

This is my menu code:

```
 -(IBAction) backgroundMusicStart{

if( i != 1){
NSURL * URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/backgroundMusic.wav", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
NSError *error;
backgroundPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL error:&error];
backgroundPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;

    [backgroundPlayer play];
    i = 1;
    NSLog(@"In start music");
}
else if ( i == 1 ) {
[backgroundPlayer stop];
    i = 0;
    NSLog(@"In stop music");
  }

}
```

"i" is a globally declared variable.

The problem with the code:
it runs, NSLog outputs that it gets into both if statements fine, the problem is when it is in the [backgroundPlayer stop] bracket, it doesnt stop the music, and I cant figure out why.

Comment: Depending on what your use case is, you might want to use pause instead of stop, the determination of which to use depends on whether you want the [play to resume or restart](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: change the nslog to NSLog(@"In stop music %@", backgroundPlayer);  and see if the background player is nil

Comment: Just as a side note, why not use a preexisting library such as cocosdenshion to handle your background music? It's a singleton that already has all of this functionality built in, you just have to call stop or start.

Comment: honestly I couldnt tell you, I watched a couple videos on youtube and read a tutorial and put it all together. As i said, were not even at this point in my class I'm just trying to step ahead and figure it out.

Comment: this is what it is outputting when I change the NSLog: <AVAudioPlayer: 0x7a7d130>

Answer (score 3):

You're initialising backgroundPlayer every time this method is invoked and in only one of the cases. What you should be doing is make backgroundPlayer an instance variable and act on the shared instance of it... Example follows:

```
// static AVPlayer *backgroundPlayer;
- (IBAction) backgroundMusicStart {
if (backgroundPlayer == nil) { 
    backgroundPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL error:&error];
    backgroundPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
}

if (i == 1) { [backgroundPlayer stop]; }
else if (i == 0) { backgroundPlayer play]; }
}
```

Comment: So I tried that and it didn't do anything. Still the same result. When I click on the button the music keeps playing:/